# Android 7.0 Native crashes due to sqlcipher library and NDK restrictions

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-7.0-nougat, sqlcipher, sqlcipher-android

I'm receiving following crash on Android 7.0 Samsung S8 and many other such native crashes:

```
backtrace:
#00  pc 000000000005da7c  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android6Parcel14freeDataNoInitEv+16)
#01  pc 00000000000f8538  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so
#02  pc 0000000002a4fa24  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Parcel.nativeDestroy+128)
#03  pc 0000000002a4ee10  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Parcel.destroy+76)
#04  pc 0000000002a5396c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Parcel.finalize+40)
#05  pc 000000000068a6e0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize+140)
#06  pc 000000000068a9bc  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal+520)
#07  pc 000000000068a054  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run+96)
#08  pc 000000000065fda0  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.Thread.run+60)
#09  pc 00000000000d25b4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+580)
#10  pc 00000000000df6e4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_Z N3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+212)
#11  pc 0000000000475fc4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+108)
#12  pc 0000000000477598  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art35InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValuesERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+372)
#13  pc 00000000004988a8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread14CreateCallbackEPv+1104)
#14  pc 00000000000770f4  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+204)
#15  pc 000000000001e7d0  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
```

This crash was logged on play store. It keeps repeating for every build update we provide on play store.

Below library is used in my app, which is the only library that uses jni code from NDK.

```
compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.9@aar'
compile 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.0.1'
```

[SQLCipher Library from Github](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher)

[Greendao Library from Github](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO)

[NDK Restrictions on Android 7.0](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#ndk)

Please help to resolve this crash issue. It is increasing day by day for my app.
See below image:

[image: Play store crashes]

[Github Issue Link](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/issues/371)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please verify you have not stored any Parcelable Objects in persistent storage like shared preferences or local sqlite db.

Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism. This class (and the corresponding Parcelable API for placing arbitrary objects into a Parcel) is designed as a high-performance IPC transport. As such, it is not appropriate to place any Parcel data in to persistent storage: changes in the underlying implementation of any of the data in the Parcel can render older data unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

The error should not be related to NDK restrictions. Just system IPC module `libbinder` crashes on releasing `Parcel` (you can check the source code here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/nougat-mr1.7-release/libs/binder/Parcel.cpp).

Check where do you send/receive data with `Parcel`/`Intent` and verify there's no errors in such places.

Also there is a huge possibility that such crashes happen only in specific cases, for example when system forcefully terminates your app - if that's the case then probably you have nothing to do with the error.

Comment: Thanks for response.we have not used any parcelable objects in app, but it seems like system forcefully terminates the app with above log. all objects are serializable.